# Type hints alter behavior of ast ClassDef base classes?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

When a class inherits a parent class with a type hint, ast returns a `base` without an `id` attribute. Why is that?

The code below prints `Parent` as I expected.

```
import ast

def print_parents(code):
    root = ast.parse(example)
    for node in root.body:
        if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):
            for base in node.bases:
                print(base.id)


example = """
class Child(Parent):
    pass
"""
print_parents(example)
```

However, this code fails:

```
example = """
class Child(Parent[str]):
    pass
"""
print_parents(example)
```

I can fix the second example by changing `base.id` to `base.value.id`, but that breaks the first example. What's happening? I've tried reading the `ast` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), but it doesn't clearly explain the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: You can't just blindly assume that the elements in `bases` will always be `Name` nodes - this has nothing to do with type hinting, you've always been able to write a function call or other expression that will return a class, rather than a literal class name.  When you pass `Parent[str]` as a base class, that produces a `Subscript` node.